# Maven not running on windows JDK 11, it says JAVA_HOME is not set

Tags: java, maven, java-11

This issue is driving me crazy, guys. Take a look.

I have downloaded and unzipped maven 3.6.3 on my Program Files folder, I set the environment variables properly, I think, but when I try to run:

[image]

As you can see in the following pictures, my JAVA_HOME is set right as it should be, pointing to a JDK 11:

[image]

[image]

I had no problem using that JDK until now for eclipse and maven inside eclipse. I've reinstalled Java already, reboot several times, but nothing seems to fix

Comment: Could it be as simple as the space in "Program Files"?  Just speculating, but you might try setting your `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-11.0.7` and see what happens then.

Comment: try `where javac` to see what Windows thinks the path to it is.

Comment: And I guess the path to jdk-11.0.7 doesn't exist on your system anymore. Did you do an upgrade of Java 11 recently with updating JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. @RobertScholte your tip was nice, actually I had the folder on filesystem but `where javac` returned that java and javac actually are inside `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My system had some misconfiguration and I cant understand why. But to solve the problem I deleted the jdk folder, removed java from official uninstaller, donwloaded and installed OpenJDK 11 from this [link](https://access.cdn.redhat.com/content/origin/files/sha256/f2/f219969b5fd88e91d0ab17e16c374d48fa992ec9e4102ebace1c1d32a9fd1493/java-11-openjdk-11.0.8.10-2.windows.redhat.x86_64.msi?_auth_=1605619251_24f6476db5ac859f08c68e228835f2ea#_=_) and the problem was solved, maven now works:

[image]

Thank you guys for your help!